# Insert into wp_postmeta table using ids from select statement

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wordpress

**I have the following query working:**

```
    SELECT  ID 
    FROM `wp_posts` as ps 
    INNER JOIN `wp_term_relationships` as tr 
    ON ps.ID = tr.object_id 
    WHERE ps.post_date < '2011-06-07' /*Get posts before June 6th 2011*/ 
    AND ps.post_title 
    LIKE '%MY SEARCH STRING %' /*A String im looking for in post titles*/ 
    AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = '548'/*My Category ID*/;
```

**I need the query to Insert specific data for each of the resulted IDs. In theory:**

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_postmeta (post_id,meta_key, meta_value)
 VALUES (IDs from selection above,_thumbnail_id,11059)
```

**This would set the `meta_key` to `_thumbnail_id` and `meta_value` to `11059` on all the posts from the specific selection above.**

*while skipping inserting any value into `wp_postmeta` auto increment column of `meta_id` by using `wp_postmeta (post_id ..)` and not `wp_postmeta (meta_id,post_id ..)`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT ID, '_thumbnail_id', 11059
FROM `wp_posts` as ps 
INNER JOIN `wp_term_relationships` as tr ON ps.ID = tr.object_id 
WHERE ps.post_date < '2011-06-07'
AND ps.post_title LIKE '%MY SEARCH STRING %'
AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = '548'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_postmeta
SELECT ID, NULL, 11059
FROM `wp_posts` as ps 
INNER JOIN `wp_term_relationships` as tr ON ps.ID = tr.object_id 
WHERE ps.post_date < '2011-06-07'
AND ps.post_title LIKE '%MY SEARCH STRING %'
AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = '548';
```